# Can I set up Hornetq Core-Bridges between two different Hornetq Server Versions?

Tags: hornetq

I have to set up a Hornetq Core-Bridge to a Hornetq 2.1.X Server, but I would like to use a more updated version on my side of the architecture (2.2.X). Is it compatible?

I haven't found info about it on documentation (as always btw, regarding to hornetq).

Obs: The 2.1.X Server is running on a JBoss AS, and mine is on stand-alone mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until hornetq 2.2.2, hornetq didn't have version compatibility support. That means that you would need all your servers on the same version. (same as you would need for your clients).

After hornetQ 2.2.2 we offer version compatibility, however the client has to be older than the server. We don't test a 2.2.5 talking to a 2.2.2 server.

So, if the core-bridge is installed in a 2.2.2 talking to a 2.2.5, you would be fine.

a 2.2.5 talking to a 2.2.2.. probably not

A 2.1.X talking to 2.2.x.. definitely not.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I'll use the same version on my side of the communication. And just to know, what about JMS Bridges? Is there any issue regarding to versions?

Comment: JMS Bridges are talking JMS. You should be fine as long as you have the proper version being by the connection factory. In theory you could have multiple versions installed on the same application server with some class loading isolation, but this is a bit complex to manage.  In practice you will need the same versions between different hornetq versions